# Drop Down setting to null on selecting a dependent drop down in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have requirement where i am getting the data from database and then creating a dropdown.depending on the values selected from the first dropdown i am using select query on the database and then getting the second drop down.

But my issue is when i am tryign to select the second dropdown, the first dropdown is setting to null.

Comment: post the code, what you have tried so far

Comment: @user5742571 Welcome to stackoverflow. here you can post your questions & query but with the efforts which you tried before posting question.As your question may have broad context so define it in detail & code which you tried for that query